# Installing a ceiling fan with a pigtail

Tags: ceiling-fan

I am wondering if I can power a ceiling fan/light by connecting it's wiring to a pigtail and plugging it into a standard 110 outlet. It will be controlled with the remote module. It will not have a wall switch at all.

Any issues with this?

Edit: The fan in question would be installed in a sunroom that I had added on to the house. Two walls are solid brick, as they were the exterior walls of the house before the room was added. And the other two walls are completely glass, as it has three large sliding glass doors to open out onto the deck.

So, due to the fact that the room is half brick and half glass, any new wiring would have to be run through conduit on top of the brick, unless I want to spend an enormous amount of time and effort trying to route it behind the brick. Given that these were exterior walls, this would not be an easy task.

Since there is already an outlet right next to the ceiling to power my outdoor sound system, I decided it would just be easier to use a pigtail to power the fan, and use a remote to operate it. I want to minimize the conduit as much as possible, so I wanted to forgo the wall switch(s).

As far as the electrical from the fan to the outlet, I haven't quite decided on the visual part of it yet. But rest assured, I will find a way to make it as aesthetically pleasing as possible. After all, I wouldn't want anyone to get the wrong idea about my socioeconomic status.

Comment: How do you plan to *mount* the thing?!

Comment: This sounds like a cord connected install. Cords are not allowed by code for permanent installations. If the ceiling is exposed conduit to a new box would be the code compliant method.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to keep your socioeconomic status, and stay within code. You'll want to grab power from the receptacles feed, not the receptacles. That is, you'll want to use properly rated cables or wires to connect to the line feeding the receptacle, rather than plugging in an extension cord.

You'll want to install a box listed and labeled to support a ceiling fan. If the rafters are exposed, installing conduit between the receptacle box and the fan box is a good option. If the ceiling is finished, you'll have to fish cable between the boxes.

Once the wires are in place, simply make the connections at both ends.  Use pigtails to slit the feed coming into the receptacle box, so that it feeds both the receptacle and the fan. Then wire up the fan as described in the manufacturer's installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Could be mounted almost as normal, to a fan-rated electrical box which is in turn mounted firmly to rafter(s). If rafters are bare this is especially straightforward, but even if there is a ceiling it doesn't seem any more complicated than a normal installation (though one would then want to use proper ceiling-rated cable at least until it exits to surface). If there are no rafters, finding adequate support is a problem no matter how you route wires.

The critical thing, I think, is making sure the *mechanical* installation is solid. These things are not light weight; it can't hang from the cable, and you do not want the risk of someone being hit if it vibrates itself loose. (Many now have a safety cable that can be separately secured; I think that's not required in earthquake-prone areas but it's cheap insurance anywhere.)

I'd have to see the specific situation, but it sounds doable.